# Windows Server 2012 R2 Update Notification on login spash screen

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

we are have two load balanced svr 2012 R2 machines, front end netscaler, using citrix reciever to login.  The issue i have is i cannot seem to disable the notifications when users are logging in that says that there are updates available in bright yellow.. in past Os we have been able to manage this with simple GPO and suppress pop ups.  I have used the GPO:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications

but this only suppresses the pop-ups and not the @profile login splash screen page.

Using this version as a Citrix TS environment means i'd rather not have these notifications as users tend to panic..

I hope that i have formatted this correctly, and i have searched to see if this had been resolved before with out luck.

Thanks

Comment: Just trying to picture which update notification you mean are you able to get a screenshot? Have you tried changing this GPO area User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Remove access to use all Windows Update features

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable update popup on Windows 2012 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/644163/disable-update-popup-on-windows-2012-r2)