# Suppress windows 'updates are available' notification on server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update, notification

In our test environment, we approve updates in WSUS and all machine in the test OU are set to automatically download and notify to install these updates. The scheduled install time is Saturday night, but throughout the week I keep seeing an 'updates are available' full screen notification on every test machine I sign in to. I don't want to see these, because the installs are scheduled for Saturday and I don't want to accidentally click install during business hours.

Here's an example of the notification I'm talking about:
[image: Here's an example of the notification I'm talking about]

I already set the group policy to disable non-admins from seeing these on their personal computers. But non-admins won't log in to our servers, so that doesn't resolve anything here.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to suppress that message for administrators.

Comment: I assume you want to take advantage of the opportunity to download the updates during the week, rather than delaying the approval of the update until off hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable update popup on Windows 2012 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/644163/disable-update-popup-on-windows-2012-r2)

Comment: This thing is dangerous!  I was typing on a server a few minutes ago and I pressed the spacebar, and it almost started installing!  Damn the GUI!